# Grep a word and need to replace the above line for that particular tag

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have HTML code as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style=width:30%>
<tr>
<td>version2</td>
<td>FAIL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>version1</td>
<td>FAIL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>version6</td>
<td>PASS</td>
</tr>
```

Whenever I see the keyword FAIL in  tags then I need to replace the above code as below. For PASS no need to do anything.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style=width:30%>
<tr bgcolor="red">
<td>version2</td>
<td>FAIL</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="red">
<td>version1</td>
<td>FAIL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>version6</td>
<td>PASS</td>
</tr>
```

Using sed I can search for a word and I can replace it by using below command:

```
sed -i 's/<tr>/<tr bgcolor="red">/g'
```

But in my case first I need to search for FAIL keyword then that particular `<tr>` tag needs to be replaced.

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible to parse XML files with regex, with sed. Use xml aware tools. Like xmllint.

Comment: It's not like it's *completely impossible;* you could write an aircraft simulator in `sed` if you really really really wanted to. But you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
             RS="<tr>|</tr>" 
           } 
$0 ~ /FAIL/ { 
             print "<tr bgcolor=\"red\">"$0"</tr>" 
            } 
$0 ~ /PASS/ { 
             print "<tr>"$0"</tr>" 
            }
!/PASS/ && !/FAIL/ { 
             print $0 
            }' html
```

One liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="<tr>|</tr>" } $0 ~ /FAIL/ { print "<tr bgcolor=\"red\">"$0"</tr>" } $0 ~ /PASS/ { print "<tr>"$0"</tr>" } !/PASS/ && !/FAIL/ { print $0 }' html
```

Using awk with a file named html, set the record separator to opening or closing tr tags, Then search the record ($0) for FAIL printing the tr tags with $0 accordingly. Do the same for PASS.

Comment: it is working fine but it is not recognizing the HTML code other than <tr> </tr> tags

Comment: Well there was no other html in your example. Perhaps you could update?

Comment: I have updated the answer to take account of any other HTML

Comment: OK. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks Raman but I didn't understand the code fully.. getting confusion. But it is working fine.. Can you please walk me through the code. I really appreciate your efforts especially that $0.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk, to define a multi-character Record Separator:

```
awk -v RS='<tr>' 'NR > 1 { rs = /FAIL/ ? "<tr bgcolor=\"red\">" : RS } { printf "%s%s", rs, $0 }' file
```

This uses the opening `<tr>` tag as the record separator and replaces it if `/FAIL/` matches any part of the record.

We use `NR > 1` so that this only starts happening after the first record, to avoid getting an extra `<tr>` at the start of the output. For the first record (everything up to the first `<tr>` in the input), `rs` is left unset, so will evaluate to an empty string when printed.

Comment: @Fenech, with the above code it is getting replaced for FAIL keyword tag along with the above PASS keyword tag as well.

Comment: I ran it with your sample input and it only changed the `<tr>` containing `FAIL`. Perhaps your real input is a bit different?

Comment: @Rama I just realised there was a mistake in my answer, and it was adding a `<tr>` to the start of the output. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

As per your Samples, Can you please try the following one.

```
tac file | awk '/<td>FAIL<\/td>/{y=1} y && /^<tr>/{print "<tr bgcolor=\"red\">";next} {print}' | tac
```

I am using tac and awk solution for the same, where tac will read the file in reverse order and awk will process the records as per given condition. Further to this, passing awk cmd output to tac to get the records in desired order

Comment: with the above even for the PASS keyword also it is getting replaced until and unless it encounters FAIL keyword.

Comment: @Rama, I think that flag needs to be turned off, after condition is met is the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution which buffers the input. It also handles indentation and lets other HTML elements pass through.

```
# if current line starts a table row, save it in tr
$0 ~ "<tr>" { tr = $0; next }

# if we are inside a table row, append it to tr
$0 !~ "</tr>" && tr != "" { tr = tr "\n" $0; next }

# if current line ends a table row, insert bgcolor if needed
# and print the previously saved tr variable
$0 ~ "</tr>" {
    if (index(tr, "<td>FAIL</td>") > 0) {
        sub("<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=\"red\">", tr)
    }
    print tr "\n" $0
    tr = ""
    next
}

# when current line is not inside a table row just print it
{ print }
```

If the script is stored in `highlight-failing.awk` and the HTML in `versions.html`, the command can be invoked with

```
awk -f highlight-failing.awk versions.html
```

Comment: in the above code where we need to pass our input file.